# Tailwind styles don't work with a conditional

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I was trying to paint a component with Tailwind, the problem is that if I pass a "color" as a prop to the component, it paints the color that I send it and if not, it paints a default color.The problem is that neither color is displayed.
This is my code:

```
export default function UIStepBlurp({ ico, number, description, color }) {

    let styleCustomColor = `items-center justify-center pt-2 border-2 rounded-full text-[14px] flex absolute -left-4 bg-white -top-4 h-[33px] w-[33px] border-[${color}]`;
    let styleDefaultColor = "items-center justify-center pt-2 border-2 rounded-full text-[14px] flex absolute -left-4 bg-white -top-4 h-[33px] w-[33px] border-primary";

    return (
        <div className="flex relative w-[175px] h-[180px] shadow-lg bg-white rounded-xl px-[4px] flex-col items-center justify-start pt-[20px]" >
            <div className={`${color ? styleCustomColor : styleDefaultColor}`}>{number}</div> // here is the conditional.
            <div className="w-20 h-20 mb-[10px] bg-no-repeat bg-contain" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${ico})` }} />
            <div className="text-[16px] leading-tight text-center mx-[10px] font-bold">{description}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is my code where I send all the props:

```
 <UIStepBlurp number={1} ico="image" description="Accede al catálogo de cursos." color="#000" />
```

Comment: You cannot use dynamic values the way you're trying in Tailwind. Tailwind must see the full value. https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind won't work when passing variables to Arbitrary Values. You can pass this color into an element's style instead:

```
export const Example = ({ color }) => (
   <div style={{ borderColor: color }} />
)
```

Or if you want to strictly use Tailwind you could create an enum with all the colors you expect to use and then choose color/class with the prop you are passing:

```
const COLORS = {
  COLOR_A: "border-[#000]",
  COLOR_B: "border-[#fff]",
}

export const Example = ({ color }) => (
   <div className={`class-1 class-2 ${COLORS[color]}`} />
)
```